# How to force an html element to load first - RoR

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, loading

Im have 2 drop down menus on my website that use the isotope plugin to filter items on the site. The problem is that those drop down menus take time to appear on the page, which is a problem especially on mobile devices because users might scroll down before they are even loaded and completely miss them. You can see the problem for yourself on my website www.shopwatchkw.com. The drop down menus are displayed in red and blue.

How can I make it so the two drop down menus either load faster or before the rest of the page is loaded so that users wont potentially miss it? I should point out that the options for the drop down menu are being populated through database requests from a `Category` and `Mall` model, and they are not static html text.

Here is the relevant code:

index.html.erb

```
<div class="filter-select">
  <div id="filterGroup">
    <select class="filter option-set selectpicker" data-filter-group="category" data-style="btn-category" data-size="false" title=" Choose a Category..">
      <option data-filter-value="" selected="selected">All Categories</option>
      <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <option data-filter-value=".category<%= category.id %>"><%= category.category_type %></option>
      <% end %> 
    </select>  
    <select class="filter option-set selectpicker" data-filter-group="location" data-style="btn-location" data-size="false" title="Choose a Location..">
     <option data-filter-value="" selected="selected">All Locations</option>
     <% @malls.each do |mall| %>
     <option data-filter-value=".mall<%= mall.id %>"><%= mall.name %></option>
     <% end %>        
   </select> 
 </div>   
</div>
```

I'm not sure what other code would be useful but please let me know if you need more specific code.

Comment: maybe you can try a different approach to stylize those dropdowns.. it's slow because of twitter bootstrap...

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response. Just so I understand how can you tell that bootstrap is what is slowing it down?